# Expert Guidance on Body Posture when Playing Bansuri

Tags: technique, bansuri, posture

So far when I play Bansuri, my torso is twisted to the left, while sitting cross-legged on my bed (and I attempt to sit straight). And my head is slightly bent at an angle.

I see others playing Bansuri also sitting cross-legged (on the floor), but their torso is facing forward. And their head is slightly bent at an angle.

Initially when I try this alternate position, I get more air into my Bansuri, but I get tired sooner.

Please tell me if there is recommended guidance for body posture when playing Bansuri.

Somehow I am thinking my body posture is causing me to breathe less air into my Bansuri (plus I am beginner at less than a year practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with:
[Posture for playing](https://drcatesflutetips.wordpress.com/tag/flute-posture-2/)

Then investigate comparable sitting postures in Yoga that emphasize freeing pressure on the diaphragm. Using chest muscles for breathing will tire the player quickly. Use of the diaphragm in breathing is a technique used not only by many woodwind players, but also martial arts practitioners. Try sitting on the floor to give the lower back more support and consequently reinforce the diaphragm. A bed, while immediately more comfortable, will certainly not offer the base provided by the floor.

Of course, more practice will strengthen all of the muscles used in playing.

Please refer to tags on this forum for breathing, woodwinds, bansuri, flute, for many useful tips.

Comment: Wow this is a low to chew on! Will start by sitting on the floor!